# I did define but why asking checkBrackets not defined

Tags: python

I did define the class as below but it gives me error message says, name 'checkBrackets' is not defined.---> 50 result = checkBrackets(equation)

I did define the class as below but it gives me error message says, name 'checkBrackets' is not defined.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []
        
    
    def push(self, item):
        self.stack.append(item)
    
    def isEmpty (self): 
        return len(self.stack) == 0
    
    def peek (self):
        if len(self.stack) != 0:
            return self.stack[-1]    
        
    def pop(self):
        if len(self.stack) != 0:
            return self.stack.pop(-1)
    

    ### 

    def checkBrackets(statement):
        
        stack = Stack()
        size = 0
        flag = "Wrong"
        
        for ch in statement:
            if ch in ('{','[','('):
                size += 1
                statck.push(ch)
            elif ch in ('}',']',')'):
                size += 1
                if stack.isEmpty():
                    return (flag, size)
                else:
                    left = stack.pop()
                    if (ch=="}" and left !="{") or (ch=="]" and left !="[") or (ch==")" and left !="(") : 
                        return (flag, size)

        if stack.isEmpty():
            flag ="OK"
            return (flag, size)
        else:
            return (flg, size) 
        

equation = input ("Enter_qauation: ")
result = checkBrackets(equation)
print ("%s_%d"%(result[0],result[1]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is defined, but it is defined in the class `Stack` so you need to call it as `Stack.checkBrackets(equation)`. There were two more errors(spelling errors), so the final code looks like:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []
        
    
    def push(self, item):
        self.stack.append(item)
    
    def isEmpty (self): 
        return len(self.stack) == 0
    
    def peek (self):
        if len(self.stack) != 0:
            return self.stack[-1]    
        
    def pop(self):
        if len(self.stack) != 0:
            return self.stack.pop(-1)
    

    ### 

    def checkBrackets(statement):
        
        stack = Stack()
        size = 0
        flag = "Wrong"
        
        for ch in statement:
            if ch in ('{','[','('):
                size += 1
                stack.push(ch) # spelling correction
            elif ch in ('}',']',')'):
                size += 1
                if stack.isEmpty():
                    return (flag, size)
                else:
                    left = stack.pop()
                    if (ch=="}" and left !="{") or (ch=="]" and left !="[") or (ch==")" and left !="(") : 
                        return (flag, size)

        if stack.isEmpty():
            flag ="OK"
            return (flag, size)
        else:
            return (flag, size) # spelling correction
        

equation = input ("Enter_equation: ")
result = Stack.checkBrackets(equation) # Changed Line
print ("%s_%d"%(result[0],result[1]))
```

Sample Output 1:

```
Enter_qauation: 
(1+2)=3
OK_2
```

Sample Output 2:

```
Enter_qauation: 
1+2=(3
Wrong_1
```

Comment: omg, thanks a lot, I figured there is also a Stack erros which you explained here. Thanks!

Comment: Also, quick question 1) if I dont use "Stack." , instead I indent last part inside of class, is it the same logic? 2) are there anyway I can improve spelling problems? I feel like it is time consuming with human eyes :(

Comment: Sorry, where do I accept the asnwer? I am new here, will do if kindly let me know where is the accept button  =p

Comment: Not exactly the same. Inside the `checkBrackets(statement)` statement, you create a stack object. This object cannot be called from the same scope as the Class. Though it would work if you unindent the `checkBrackets()` function out of the class. And the button is the arrow on the left side of my answer(below the votes)

Comment: *Tick Mark below the votes